# Pass data to Angular element component

Tags: angular, typescript, element, custom-element

Given I have a component which I want to export and use as a standalone angular-element-component.

```
export class CompanyFormComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() public companyId: string;
company: Company;
companyForm: FormGroup;



constructor(
    private companyService: CompanyService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

ngOnInit() {

if (!this.companyId || this.companyId.length === 0) {
  console.log('Please provide an Id');
}
```

....

AppModule:

```
    export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const strategyFactory = new ElementZoneStrategyFactory(CompanyFormComponent, this.injector);
    const element = createCustomElement(CompanyFormComponent, { injector: this.injector, strategyFactory });
    customElements.define('app-company-form', element);
  } 
}
```

Index.html:

```
<app-company-form></app-company-form>
```

I want to be able to inject any value where ever I use this component, as simple as:

```
<app-company-form companyId=11></app-company-form>
```

So the companyId can be populated from another place, completely outside Angular. I don't want to hard code the value inside angular.

I have tried a few things, but nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

when you use your component as a custom/angular element you can pass the companyId input parameter by adding the following html attribute to your custom element.

```
<app-company-form company-id="11"></app-company-form>
```

Comment: naw I'm a mere mortal, the devs at google that build angular are the Magicians

Comment: Thanks for your help @cobolstinks

Comment: This won't work with [company-id]="myVar" right? It looks like a limitation of web components.

Comment: Thank you @cobolstinks